# its possible add .setView on L.geoJson?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

sorry it's me again, this time i need add a some type of .SetView on L.geoJson, to be clearer. i try to a make L.control.layers redirect the view (coordinates) every time that click on the items, i think the right way to do this, it's this:

```
var rutavistaimss = L.geoJson(rutavs,{color:'#1212fe'}).setView([25.4197,-100.991295], 13);
```

but don't works.

her this my code:

```
var rutavistaimss = L.geoJson(rutavs,{color:'#1212fe'}); 
var rutavspos = L.geoJson(rutavspostal,{color:'#1212fe'});
var rutavscen = L.geoJson(rutavscentro,{color:'#1212fe'});
var ruta8ampli = L.geoJson(ruta8AmpMo,{color:'#6d418b'});
var ruta8moimss = L.geoJson(ruta8imss,{color:'#6d418b'});
var ruta18D = L.geoJson(ruta18d,{color:'green'});
var rutaperife = L.geoJson(rutaperi,{color:'#de3030'});
var rutamirasi = L.geoJson(rutamira,{color:'#f2ec00'});




//paradas de ruta vista imss
var paradasrutavs = paradasrutavspre;

var rutatodoeuno = L.layerGroup([paradasrutavspre,rutavistaimss]);


var capaderutas = {
    "ruta vista imss": rutatodoeuno,
    'ruta vista postal':rutavspos,
    'ruta vista centro':rutavscen,
    "ruta 18 directa": ruta18D ,
    "ruta periferico": rutaperife,
    "ruta mira sierra": rutamirasi,
    "ruta 8 ampliacion morelos": ruta8ampli,
    'ruta 8 morelos imss':ruta8moimss
};

L.control.layers(null,capaderutas,{collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
```

i hope anyone can help me and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layers control has some events which are useful. If you simply want the view to pan/zoom to include the features on the overlay you've selected, you can do this:

Wherever you instantiate the map

```
map.on('overlayadd', function(e) {
  map.fitBounds(e.layer.getBounds());
});
```

Comment: well that works, but it seems that it does not in layergroup.
`var rutatodoeuno = L.layerGroup([paradasrutavspre,rutavistaimss]);`